# RequireJS, Jasmine and Grunt Error: scripterror: Illegal path or script error

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs, jasmine

I have an application which uses requireJS, and I would like to use grunt-contrib-jasmie to test it. In order to get jasmine to work with require I am using cloudchen's grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs. The application has the following directory structure:

```
topLevelApplicationFolder    
|_app.html
|_Gruntfile.js
|_package.json
|_js
  |_app.js
  |_app
    |_modules
      |_rgbaHelpers.js
      |_main.js
   |_lib
     |_require.js
|_spec
  |_rgba_spec.js
```

app.js is my requireJS config file:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "js/lib",
    paths: {
      app: "../app"
    },
    shim: {
        spectrum: {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "spectrum"
        }
    }
});

// Load the main app module to start the app
requirejs(["app/main"]);
```

And my Gruntfile.js is the following:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    jasmine : {
        taskName: {
            src : 'js/**/*.js',
            options : {
                specs : 'spec/**/*.js',
                template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
                templateOptions: {
                    requireConfig: {
                        baseUrl: 'js/lib'
                    }
                // requireConfigFile: './js/app.js'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    jshint: {
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            'js/**/*.js',
            'spec/**/*.js'
        ],
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.registerTask('test', ['jshint', 'jasmine']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['test']);
```

};

The rgba_spec.js is the test I would like to run. It is very simple:

```
define(['js/app/modules/rgbaHelpers'], function (rgbaHelpers) {
    describe('A suite', function() {
        it('should pass this test', function() {
            expect(rgbaHelpers).not.toBe(null);
        });
    });
});
```

But when I run grunt jasmine I get the following error:

```
Error: scripterror: Illegal path or script error: ['js/app/modules/rgbaHelpers']
```

I have been scratching my head over this all day. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to fix this issue by completely removing the requireConfig and baseURL from the template options:

```
    jasmine : {
        taskName: {
            src : 'js/**/*.js',
            options : {
                specs : 'spec/**/*.js',
                template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
                templateOptions: {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then at the top of each spec I would do something like this:

```
define(['js/app/modules/mouseHelpers'], function (mouseHelpers) {
```